# How much does model fit affect the analysis of an invariance test?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, group-differences, invariance

I am currently running a group invariance test with R, lavaan.
My total sample is 794. The results came out as the attached photo.

[image]

I understand that the chi-sq, CFI, and RMSEA all indicate that full
invariance holds within the groups but it concerns me that the RMSEA
value itself goes from "not optimal" to "bad".
Is this an issue to be concerned about as in terms of invariance testing?
Or should I at least perform a partial invariance test to improve model fit?
Also, if someone could comment on how the increase in RMSEA fits in the invariance
test context that will be very much appreciated.
(I have tried to reach Chen(2007) but I couldn't access it)
Thank you all for your kind help.

Comment: Could you provide the full citation of Chen 2007?

Comment: I actually found the article. It is  Fang Fang Chen (2007) Sensitivity of Goodness of Fit Indexes to Lack of Measurement Invariance, Structural Equation Modeling: A Multidisciplinary Journal, 14:3, 464-504, DOI: 10.1080/10705510701301834

Comment: It is puzzling that your configural invariance model has the most df and that the metric model has the smallest overall chi-square value. The scalar model should have the most df since it involves the largest number of invariance (equality) constraints, followed by the metric model. The configural model should have the lowest number of df and typically a chi-square that is smaller than or equal to the chi-squares of the other models.

Comment: Also, neither your absolute model fit chi-square nor the RMSEA values look good for any of the models. I would examine the reasons of the misfit in the configural model first. The problems likely carry over into the more constrained model versions.

Comment: Sir Geiser, Thank you for pointing out the changes in df. As you say, it is quite strange. I should go back and check the configural model and the syntax itself, too.

Comment: Dr. Geiser. I re-did the whole analysis on a different software and got more understandable results. Thank you for pointing out odd values in my results.